# Why this error? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE

Tags: php

I'm making a system to change my password and I don't know why I am getting this error.
I have this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/zenonhos/public_html/system/changepass.php on line 37

```
<?php
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

if ($user)
{

    if ($_POST['submit'])
    {
        $oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
        $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);
        $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);


        $connect = mysql_connect("*******","******","*****");
        mysql_select_db("zenonhos_lr");

        $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE username='$user'") or die();
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
        $oldpassworddb = $row['password']; 

        if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)
        {
            if ($newpassword == "") {
                echo "Password cannot be blank";
            } else {

                if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
                {
                    $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$user'");

                    session_destroy();
                    die("Password successfully changed! <a href='index.php'>Return to home page</a>");
                } else {
                    die("New passwords do not match");
                } else {
                    die("Old password does not match");
                } echo "<form action='changepass.php' method='POST'>
                    Old Password: <input type='password' name='oldpassword'><br>
                    New Password: <input type='password' name='newpassword'><br>
                    Repeat New Password: <input type='password' name='repeatnewpassword'><br>
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Change Password'>";
            } else {
                die("You must be logged in to view this page.");
            }

?>
```

Comment: Please, read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation

Comment: hmm can you use 2 else in a row? "else {
                    die("New passwords do not match");
                } else {"

Comment: @Shadow_boi is correct, I think (you should submit that as an answer :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in ..... modules.php on line 243](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859403/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-else-in-modules-php-on-line-243)

Comment: Your variables will never be empty. MD5 of an empty string is not empty.

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. Don't use [`or die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) when outputting HTML. You'll get invalid HTML.

Comment: [MD5 is considered broken](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/12/forging_ssl_cer.html) by security professionals. Use a tunable [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) and per-user salt to protect the accounts from [rainbow tables](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html) and brute-force attacks. You can upgrade the hashes without impacting users by adding extra columns to the password table to recorde the salt and hash algorithm use, and re-hashing upon successful login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed tree `}` and  there were two sintax errors because of two `else`. Below is your code updated.

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

if ($user)
{
    if ($_POST['submit'])
    {
        $oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
        $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);
        $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);

        $connect = mysql_connect("*******","******","*****");
        mysql_select_db("zenonhos_lr");

        $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE username='$user'") or die();
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
        $oldpassworddb = $row['password']; 

        if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)
        {
            if ($newpassword == "") 
            {
                echo "Password cannot be blank";
            } 
            else 
            {

                if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
                {
                    $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$user'");

                    session_destroy();
                    die("Password successfully changed! <a href='index.php'>Return to home page</a>");
                } 
                else 
                {
                    die("Old password does not match");
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
}

echo "
    <form action='changepass.php' method='POST'>
    Old Password: <input type='password' name='oldpassword'><br>
    New Password: <input type='password' name='newpassword'><br>
    Repeat New Password: <input type='password' name='repeatnewpassword'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Change Password'>";

?>
```

Comment: That still didn't work, just gave me an error on a lower line

Comment: @JonathanSmith, Please copy and paste the code again, i've done some changes. If you get errors, put them here.

Comment: Now it doesn't even show the form and there's no error

Comment: @JonathanSmith, I've updated the code, please copy and paste again.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stressing on that so much!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the brackets of this if-statements:

```
if ($user)
{

if ($_POST['submit'])
{
if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)
{
```

To fix it, just close them by putting there `} } }` in end of your source-code.

Also, I recommend strongly read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation).